# How to change an specific keyword color on Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

So, I'm using this new scheme for Visual Studio that is called Solarized, but I want to change the brackets colors and also the conditionals color like If, While etc. The problem is that if I change the color in colors and fonts, it will also change the color for a lot other things. I was looking for a way to change the color for each individual character or keyword, if someone could help, that would be great! (I'm Working with c++ btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a plugin called Viasfora, which changes the bracket's colors, also I'm using Color theme editor for Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such extension for that and there is no way in visual studio to do what you want. You would need to write some custom extension by yourself to be able to do that.

For that I can point you some useful links 
Some small extension that do colorization (it is C# as any extension in VS):

https://github.com/hicknhack-software/semantic-colorizer

Guide how to write extensions for visual studio (also C#):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885122.aspx